# How can I match my animation with transform in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animator

I have implemented a player movement and jump in my game. I also attached a run and jump animation to animator. However, the jump animation does not perfectly match with the player vertical movement. How can I match them perfectly?

Thanks in advance,

```
void Control()
{
    if (charController.isGrounded)
    {
        float h = Joystick.GetHorizontalAxis("MyJoystick");
        float v = Joystick.GetVerticalAxis("MyJoystick");

        moveDirection = new Vector3(h, 0.0f, v);
        moveDirection *= (speed * sprint);
        anim.SetFloat("WalkSpeed", moveDirection.magnitude);

        if (moveDirection.magnitude > 0.5)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("WalkSpeed", moveDirection.magnitude / speed);
            anim.SetFloat("Walk", 1.0f);
            transform.forward = moveDirection;
        }

        else if (moveDirection.magnitude > 0 && moveDirection.magnitude < 0.5)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("WalkSpeed", moveDirection.magnitude / (speed * 0.5f));
            anim.SetFloat("Walk", 0.5f);
            transform.forward = moveDirection;
        }

        else if (moveDirection.magnitude == 0)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Walk", 0f);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }
    }

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    charController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the Animator component to do what you want.

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html) is a link that describes it in more details.